# Rank One decrease

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $X$ be a $N\times N$ real positive semi-definite(p.s.d) matrix with rank $R$. Let $x_1\in Range(X)$ be a non-zero $N\times 1$ vector such that $X_1=X-x_1x_1^T$ is still p.s.d. What is the rank of $X_1$? Is it $R-1$?

Comment: It could be $R$ if $x_1=0$. $0$ vector is in the range of every matrix.

Comment: @voldemort I waved my wand and just made $x_1\neq 0$. Now your turn! :)

Answer (score 1):

The rank of $X_1$ need not decrease.

A trivial example would be the following:

Let $X=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 &1
\end{pmatrix}$

Take $x_1=(1/2,1/2)^t$

Then, $X_1$ still has rank $1$.

Comment: isn't $X_1=\begin{bmatrix}0& 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ in that case?

Comment: @dineshdileep: edited my example.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.  It depends a lot on the matrix (I'll change notation, $x_1$ will be a column vector for me).  For starters, we don't know whether $x_1$ is an eigenvector or not, right?

Imagine that $x_1$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $\lambda_1 \gg 1.$  In this case, clearly $X_1=X-x_1^Tx_1$ would still be p.s.d.

The corresponding $X_1$ is p.s.d. if and only if, for every vector $v$, one has:

$$\langle v, Xv \rangle \geq \langle v, x_1 \rangle^2.$$

You should write $x_1$ in terms of a basis of eigenvectors of $X$ in order to study the conditions for $X_1$ to be p.s.d. more accurately.